# How to increase the RabbitMQ federation rate?

Tags: rabbitmq

It seems that I am hitting a limitation in RMQ regarding the federation. I tried different setups and configurations but I can't receive more than 4-7k messages per seconds (depend on if I configure the federation as `on-publish` or `no-ack`).

The things that I already tried:

1. federation with different configs (with and without prefetch, ack, etc)
2. multiple exchanges in RMQ1 and create the same number of federations in RMQ2 and each federation point to one different exchange in RMQ1
3. federation to queues
4. Using the Consistent Hash Exchange (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange)
5. shovel (same message rate as federation)

I want to know how I can transfer more messages from one RMQ to another.

Comment: What about the system resources of the two RMQ instances...did you tried increasing those.

Comment: I tried it on different machines including very powerful servers and I didn't put a limitation on the resources for it. But anyway resources is not related because I never seen that the RMQ consume more than 2-3 vcpu while I have seen it has used up to 20 vcpu if the load is really high. So the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of RMQ itself: https://github.com/rabbitmq/discussions/issues/65